# How to check the correct answer JavaScript (4 BUTTONS)

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a quiz game using JavaScript and I want to create a function that check the answer if correct

My goal here is to check if button clicked among the 4 buttons is correct, need to identify the correct answer for each of the questions.

Can you guide me what to do?

I have the array of objects:

```js
let myQuestions = [{
    question: "How old is LJ?",

    answers: {
      a: "27",
      b: "25",
      c: "26",
      d: "24",
      correctAnswer: "b",
    },
  },
  {
    question: "What is her favorite game?",
    answers: {
      a: "ML",
      b: "COD",
      c: "DOTA 2",
      d: "LOL",
      correctAnswer: "b",
    },

  },
  {
    question: "Where does LJ live?",
    answers: {
      a: "Pasig city",
      b: "Quezon city",
      c: "Rizal",
      d: "Sta Mesa",
      correctAnswer: "a",
    },

  }
];

//Here's my JavaScript code function to render the question and the choices everytime we click the buttons. 


function renderQuestion() {

  let show = document.getElementById('question');
  let q = myQuestions[questionIndex];

  show.innerHTML = q.question;
  questionIndex++;
  console.log(questionIndex)

  button1.innerHTML = q.answers.a;
  button2.innerHTML = q.answers.b;
  button3.innerHTML = q.answers.c;
  button4.innerHTML = q.answers.d;
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to the snippet

Comment: I suggest you use delegation from the container and test the value that you have set the button's value to

Comment: Never save answers to quiz questions on the front-end in production. As answer can be easily sniffed.

Comment: @wokorodouyesamuel ONLY save answers on the front-end when they are not important

Comment: @mplungjan what is your definition of not important answers

Comment: If this is a fan page and a quiz for the friends of Joy (and judging from the questions it likely is), and no one wins anything for answering, then perhaps it is OK to have the answers in the source code of the page. If it is a competition and the winners get a date with LJ, then perhaps you are correct?

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Haha! LJ is actually me and questions there are just example. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Assuming this quiz is not important (anyone can see the answers in the source)

I moved the correctAnswer outside the list of answers

```js
let myQuestions = [{ question: "How old is LJ?", answers: { a: "27", b: "25", c: "26", d: "24", }, correctAnswer: "b", }, { question: "What is her favorite game?", answers: { a: "ML", b: "COD", c: "DOTA 2", d: "LOL", }, correctAnswer: "b", }, { question: "Where does LJ live?", answers: { a: "Pasig city", b: "Quezon city", c: "Rizal", d: "Sta Mesa", }, correctAnswer: "a", } ];

let questionIndex = 0;

function renderQuestion() {
  if (questionIndex >= myQuestions.length) return;
  let show = document.getElementById('question');
  let q = myQuestions[questionIndex];
  show.innerHTML = q.question;
  Object.entries(q.answers).forEach(([letter,text]) => {
    const but = document.getElementById(letter);
    but.innerHTML = text
    but.dataset.correct = q.correctAnswer === letter;
  })
  questionIndex++;
}
renderQuestion()

document.getElementById("buts").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type === "button") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = tgt.dataset.correct === "true" ? "Correct" : "Incorrect"
  }
})

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", renderQuestion)
```

```html
<span id="question"></span> <span id="result"></span>
<div id="buts">
  <button type="button" id="a"></ button>
  <button type="button" id="b"></ button>
  <button type="button" id="c"></ button>
  <button type="button" id="d"></ button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```